# How does KVM set the X/XU bit for EPT?

Tags: kvm, virtual-memory

I am interested in the X/XU bit of EPT in the [Intel Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm). 
The XU bit(bit 10 of EPT) indicates the execute access for user-mode linear addresses, while X bit(bit 2 of EPT) controls execute access for supervisor-mode linear addresses.

I want to know if KVM enables this feature? And how can KVM decide to set/clear these two bits?

Can someone help me? Great thanks.

---

These two bits are described in the notes 3, 4 of Figure 28-1 in Volume 3(3A, 3B, 3C & 3D): System Programming Guide.

[image]